# memcpy of a three dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

We can copy the entire 3d array contents into another 3d array using memcpy in a very clean way. I wanted to know if there is any cleaner way of copying few contents of a 3d array into another.

```
void function()
{
    uint32_t array1[2][2][2];
    uint32_t array2[2][2][2];
    //memset both the arrays to 0 first;
    memset(&array1,0,sizeof(array1));
    memset(&array2,0,sizeof(array2));

    array1[0][1][1]= 4;
    array1[0][0][0]=6;
    //memcpy(&array2,&array1,sizeof(array1)); 

    memcpy(&array2[0][1][1],&array1[0][1][1],sizeof(array1[0][1][1])); //this works, but if there is a cleaner way?
    printf_all("value of array1 %d and array2 %d \n",array1[0][1][1],array2[0][1][1]);
}
```

Comment: This should actually work: memcpy(array2,array1,sizeof(array1)); and is nice , clean and compact

Comment: Btw, you may want to use "= {0}" instead of memset to 0.

Comment: For single elements a simple assignment is probably the easiest to understand when someone reads the code later. Copying blocks which span more than one increment of the last index is dangerous since you have to know how the array is laid out in memory.

Comment: 1) memset(&array1, 0, sizeof(array1)); - memset should take pointer to memory.

2) Since this is stack alocated array, you can assign arrays of same size directly and it should 'just work'.

3) In C99-C11 standards you don't need to memset them at runtime, simply define them as uint32_t array[2][2][2] = {0};
and it should zero them during build (compiler might be already doing it tho).

4) array is a 'pointer' by automagically, you don't want to dereference stack variable that holds your pointer like that.

Comment: @ChrisRyding We know how the arrays are laid out because the language specifies it. C and C++ use row major order. It's perfectly safe to use `memcpy` to copy multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
memcpy( &array2[0][1][1],
        &array1[0][1][1],
        sizeof(array1[0][1][1]) ) ;
```

Achieves the same as direct element assignment:

```
array2[0][1][1] = array1[0][1][1] ;
```

To use `memcpy()` for single element assignment is somewhat over-complicated and likely less efficient.  It makes more sense if for example you were copying entire sub-arrays, e.g.:

```
memcpy( &array2[0][1],
        &array1[0][1],
        sizeof(array2[0][1]) ) ;
```

Note that it is safer to use the size of the *destination* rather the the *source* for the third argument of `memcpy()` - just in case the destination is smaller.